# Page_PreInit not called?

Tags: c#, page-lifecycle

Im running an ASP.NET 4.0 project.

The .aspx page has `AutoEventWireup="true"` set in the header.

Although `OnPreInit` is called, `Page_PreInit` is not? Can anyone suggest what is wrong?

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("bar");
}

protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("foo");
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Comment: Your syntax seems fine. Is this defined in the MasterPage?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue you described.  Is AutoEventWireup defined in the master page?

Comment: Or are you inheriting the page?

Answer (score 3):

The `Page_PreInit` event does fire, you can see this, if you put a breakpoint at the start of the event and step through it at the run time.
The reason the string "bar" is not being written to the screen is because it gets overwritten by the `OnPreInitEvent`.

Please see code below.
Step through it and you will notice how it goes into `Page_PreInit` and then gets overwritten in the `OnPreInitEvent`.
If you comment out the ENTIRE `OnPreInit` event you will see "Page_PreInit" being written to the screen.

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    string eventName = String.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(eventName);
    }

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eventName = "Page_PreInit";
    }  

    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
       base.OnPreInit(e);
       eventName = "OnPreInit";
    }
}
```