# How to change a asp webapplication theme (not page) programmatically and during runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, themes

I'm learning ASP.net and I've been playing around with themes and master pages. I decided I wanted to change the theme of the website, and used the web.config solution (adding theme to web.config). What I want to do now is to be able to change the theme based on user and the selected theme by the user.

I have been unable to find any tutorials, all of them seem to show how to change separate contentpages, but I want to change the whole site theme.

How do you go about doing that, in the simplest way? I am not connected to a database atm., it's just for practice :)

with kind regards

Comment: Themes, master pages, content pages and web.config are asp.net and not classic asp. Edited your Tags.

Comment: There are lots of examples on the web, here is one: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-user-selectable-themes-for-a-web-site I'd recommend just searching around and looking, Microsoft has posted quite a few

Comment: thank you, I forgot about that :)

Comment: This worked, but I had to hardcode the controlname as the code he used gives me a null reference exception... do you have any idea why? ( I downloaded his code o double check and got the same problem)



    `public class BasePage : Page
{
  public BasePage()
  {
  }

  protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    if (Request.Form != null && Request.Form.Count > 0)
    {
      this.Theme = Request.Form[this.Master.FindControl("DropDownList1").UniqueID];
    }

  }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base page that you inherit all your pages from and set the theme in the OnPreInit event:

```
public class ThemePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        SetTheme();            

        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }

    private void SetTheme()
    {
        this.Theme = ThemeSwitcher.GetCurrentTheme();
    }
}
```

Below is the ThemeSwitcher utility class that handles getting/saving the current theme and listing themes. Since you said you're not using a database you can use Session:

```
public class ThemeSwitcher
{
    private const string ThemeSessionKey = "theme";

    public static string GetCurrentTheme()
    {
        var theme = HttpContext.Current.Session[ThemeSessionKey]
            as string;

        return theme ?? "Default";
    }

    public static void SaveCurrentTheme(string theme)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[ThemeSessionKey]
            = theme;
    }

    public static string[] ListThemes()
    {
        return (from d in Directory.GetDirectories(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/app_themes"))
                select Path.GetFileName(d)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

You'll want a page where you can change the theme. Add a dropdownlist with the following code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : ThemePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        var currentTheme = ThemeSwitcher.GetCurrentTheme();

        foreach (var theme in ThemeSwitcher.ListThemes())
        {
            var item = new ListItem(theme);
            item.Selected = theme == currentTheme;
            ddlThemes.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    protected void ddlThemes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThemeSwitcher.SaveCurrentTheme(ddlThemes.SelectedItem.Value);
        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
    }       
}
```

You can download the sample application [here](http://storage.onfabrik.com/6724b018c1dfea1e/WebFormsThemeSwitcher.zip).

Comment: thank you for the code, it was the only thing worked, and I tried all of the above tutorials ! Pew! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this done before by inheriting all your pages from a base page

```
    public partial class _Default : BasePage
```

and in setting the theme in the base page class.

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
  {
       base.OnPreInit(e);
       Page.Theme = //Your theme;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 You should set the Theme prior to calling the base.OnPreInit(e). From MSDN "The Theme property must be set prior to the PreInit event; setting the Theme property after the PreInit event will cause an InvalidOperationException exception."

Comment: I checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/tx35bd89.aspx before I posted.  Has this changed recently or has MSDN got conflicting info.

Comment: Heres an interesting article, it says "After" the PreInit Event Page personalisation and Themes are applied. The PreInit event is an event early in the page life cycle that you can access. After the PreInit event, personalization information and the page theme, if any, is loaded.

Comment: Page_PreInit gets called prior to OnPagePreInit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676060/page-preinit-not-called

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know how it went :)

Comment: My mistake, the article said Page_PreInit as you mentioned, I just seen PreInit and assumed, oops.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these useful MSDN docs:

[Walkthrough: Creating User-Selectable Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366514.aspx)

[How to: Apply ASP.NET Themes Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Check this too:

[Master Pages and Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/wtxbf3hh.aspx#MasterPagesAndThemes)

[Scoping Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ykzx33wh.aspx#ScopingThemes)

> You cannot directly apply an ASP.NET theme to a master page. If you
>   add a theme attribute to the @ Master directive, the page will raise
>   an error when it runs.

Comment: Leniel, the tutorials are about pages, not the whole site. But thank you anyway :)